# Bypassing uniqueness validator for PUT request

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I am faced with a problem of not being able to get around a single validator that is used for checking the uniqueness of the name of an object upon POST and PUT requests. Details are provided below:

## Given,

### A class UserDTO with two fields

```
private int id

@UserUniquenessValidator
private String name
```

### The controller methods signatures

```
post(@Valid @RequestBody UserDTO userDTO)

put(@PathVariable int id, @Valid @RequestBody UserDTO userDTO)
```

### A custom validator applied on the field name

```
 @UserUniquenessValidator
```

Now, whenever I am trying to POST a new user the custom validator simply checks the name field against other records in the database and returns true if it does not find any and vice-versa.

The problem comes about every time a PUT request, with the field 'name' not changed, is sent in - the validator checks for uniqueness and does not let through as it already has an entry with the given name in the DB.

On a side note, I should mention that the constraint cannot be applied on the table in the database for reasons that are too long to explain.

Is there a clever walk-around solution to this without having to clutter the code too much? I wish there was a way of letting the validator know that anytime a PUT comes in to follow a different logic than for a POST request.

Comment: to be `@Valid`, `UserDTO` should meet the requirements of all validators including `@UserUniquenessValidator`. Why did you mark it with `@Valid` if you don't want it to be such?

Comment: are you OK with modifying the `UserUniquenessValidator` processor? (I can add an answer)

Comment: I do want it to be @Valid but it blocks any PUT requests coming in if the field 'name' is left intact - that's the only case when the validator does not work as I would like it to.

Comment: Yes, the UserUniquenessValidator can be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can assume your validator is already a Spring bean: you retrieve database records to pursue name uniqueness.

Provided that the validator is involved only in the request validation context, you can inject a `HttpServletRequest` proxy to give the validator a request context

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

from which you can figure out the current HTTP method.

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(String name, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return HttpMethod.PUT.name().equals(request.getMethod()) || 
           validate(name, context);
}

private boolean validate(String name, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    // validate name uniqueness
    return false;
}
```

To avoid hardcoding `HttpMethod.PUT.name()`, the annotation can define `String[] excludeFor`:

`@UserUniquenessValidator(excludeFor={"PUT"})`

I find the annotation name incorrect. `UserUniquenessValidator` is a good title for a class that processes this annotation but not for the annotation itself. I would name it `@UniqueName`.